# find rightmost cell in row that has text (and separate formula for the same with a number)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'd like to create an excel formula that populates cells  in a summary table of the most recent information from a table that I maintain.

Example:

[image: example illustration]

I enter my regular bills in three columns at the top - date, cost and supplier.  If I change supplier or the cost changes I put in another three columns with the updated information.

I'd like the bottom table to take the most recent information - I don't know how to use lookup to take the rightmost text (supplier) and the rightmost number (cost).

All I can do at the moment is take the rightmost value so the table says

bbc
Amber Valley
Southern Gas

in both supplier and annual cost.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In B9: `=OFFSET($A2,,COUNTA(2:2)-1)`

In C9: `=OFFSET($A2,,COUNTA(2:2)-2)`

And fill down.

Comment: I think you meant to use `COUNTA` instead of `COUNT` as some of the cells you need to count are not numeric. I try to avoid volatile functions where possible, so I would suggest `INDEX(2:2,1,COUNTA(2:2))` and `INDEX(2:2,1,COUNTA(2:2)-1)`. With that caveat, this is a better answer than mine as the formula is easier to understand. The only benefit of mine is that it works if there are empty cells in the middle of the row.

Comment: You are exactly right, thanks for pointing that out.  Need more coffee. :)

Comment: this provided the solution for me, although as @Blackwood points out, you do need to make sure that all cells, including zeros are filled in for it to run correctly.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention how you are successfully getting the rightmost value in the table. One way you might be doing that is by entering the following formula in cell B9:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(2:2<>0),2:2)
```

The way that formula works is that `2:2<>0` returns an array of True/False values indication which cells in row 2 are not blank. `1/(2:2<>"")` returns an array consisting of 1 for each non-blank cell and #DIV/0! for each blank cell. LOOKUP searches the returned array for the value 2; as it that value is not in the array, it finds that last occurrence of the next highest value (1 in this case). LOOKUP returns the value from the last parameter (2:2) that corresponds to the found value.

We can modify that formula to return the value of the cell before that last non-blank value by entering this in cell C9:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(B2:ZZ2<>0),A2:ZY2)
```

In this version, the array that the value is lookup up in is shifted left one cell from the array that was searched, resulting in the cell to to left of the last cell being returned. Note that you need to be sure that the data doesn't extend any further than the end of the ranges used in the LOOKUP (ZZ2 in my example).